# Convert unsigned char to char* and Concatenate them in C

Tags: c

I want to convert a value `unsigned char` to one of type `char*` passing values ​​through a function.

This is my program:

```
int my_function(unsigned char param1, unsigned char param2)
{
    char* buffer_char;

    const char* mss_part_1 = "Value 1: ";
    const char* mss_part_2 = " Value 2: ";

    buffer_char = malloc(240);

    strcpy(buffer_char, mss_part_1);    //OK
    strcat(buffer_char, param1);        //ERROR
    strcat(buffer_char, mss_part_2);    //OK
    strcat(buffer_char, param2);        //ERROR

    //Desire Output: "Value 1: 1234 Value 2: 5678"
    printf("%s", buffer_char);

    free(buffer_char);
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    unsigned char value1[10];
    unsigned char value2[10];

    strncpy(value1, "1234", 4);
    strncpy(value2, "5678", 4);

    my_function(value1, value2);

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is in the `strcat()` function when I try to concatenate the value as "unsigned char" but I have not found the way to convert it so I can concatenate it.

I am trying to use the `strcat()` function but if there was a more efficient form I would like to know.

Note: I have no problem displaying the output value.

Comment: `strncpy(value1, "1234", 4)` please read the manual page for strncpy() first. Or do `strncpy(value1, "1234", 5);` or just strcpy() ...

Comment: That `unsigned char` is _a single character_, just a number in range at least [0, 255].

Comment: what you actually want is sprintf.

Comment: i am sure the compiler is complaining to you about `my_function(value1,value2)` value1 is a char array but the function is defined to accept one char

Comment: just declare my_function to accept char* rather that char

Comment: Hmm. Do you want to want to convert a value `unsigned char` to one of type `char*` or convert a value `unsigned char *`to one of type `char*`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is in the function declaration and in understanding the difference between `unsigned char` and `unsigned char[]`.  In your function definition:

```
int my_function(unsigned char param1, unsigned char param2)
```

..you are stating that `my_function` accepts two parameters, each of type `unsigned char`.  To the compiler, this means that each parameter contains a single char.. which is not a pointer, but actually an 8 bit integer type.. each parameter is expected to hold a single 8 bit character.  But what you really want to pass is a pointer to an array of characters:

```
int my_function(unsigned char *param1, unsigned char *param2)
```

or

```
int my_function(unsigned char param1[], unsigned char param2[])
```

To the compiler, these both mean the same thing, because the name of an array (regardless of the type contained within the array) always evaluates to a pointer to the first element in the array.

So, when you define a variable:

```
unsigned char value1[10];
```

.. you are allocating (on the stack, in this case.. since it's a local variable) an array of 10 unsigned chars, one after the other.  But when you pass or refer to `value1`, it evaluates as the address of the first character in the array, in other words, a pointer to the array, which would be of type `unsigned char *`.

The second thing you should be thinking about is, why are you using unsigned char when it seems that your text is all regular ASCII characters that are suitable for a char array type?  There is nothing wrong with unsigned char, and the compiler will often do these conversions for you anyway, but in general when you mix up types without being aware of the consequences, you can have problems.  Be aware of what types the functions you are using expect, and try to keep this consistent.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `strncpy` doesn't automatically add the terminating NUL character `'\0'`, so you'll have to add it manually. Secondly, your function parameters are `unsigned char`, which is a single unsigned character, when they should be either `unsigned char*` or `unsigned char[]`, which is a pointer to unsigned character (a string).

This will work:

```
int my_function(unsigned char* param1, unsigned char* param2)
{
    char* buffer_char;

    const char* mss_part_1 = "Value 1: ";
    const char* mss_part_2 = " Value 2: ";

    buffer_char = malloc(240);

    strcpy(buffer_char, mss_part_1);
    strcat(buffer_char, param1);
    strcat(buffer_char, mss_part_2);
    strcat(buffer_char, param2);

    printf("%s", buffer_char);

    free(buffer_char);
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    unsigned char value1[10];
    unsigned char value2[10];

    strncpy(value1, "1234", 4);
    strncpy(value2, "5678", 4);

    value1[4] = '\0';
    value2[4] = '\0';

    my_function(value1, value2);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're passing in pointers, so the sig of the function should have pointers.

```
int my_function(unsigned char *param1, unsigned char *param2);
```

The unsigned stuff is likely a needless complication -- you might want to get rid of it in the whole program. You're also using `strncpy` wrong, are failing to error check (`malloc` may fail) , and your function's API is weak because it doesn't allow you to do any kind of bound checking.

Here's a quick and dirty fix except for the bounds-checking part:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int my_function(char *param1, char *param2)
{
    char* buffer_char;

    const char* mss_part_1 = "Value 1: ";
    const char* mss_part_2 = " Value 2: ";

    buffer_char = malloc(240);
    if(0 == buffer_char)
        return -1;

    strcpy(buffer_char, mss_part_1);
    strcat(buffer_char, param1);
    strcat(buffer_char, mss_part_2);
    strcat(buffer_char, param2);

    //Desire Output: "Value 1: 1234 Value 2: 5678"
    printf("%s", buffer_char);

    free(buffer_char);
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char value1[10];
    char value2[10];

    strncpy(value1, "1234", 10);
    strncpy(value2, "5678", 10);

    my_function(value1, value2);

    return 0;
}
```

Your compiler is probably warning you about all these errors. You should treat all the warnings as errors.